# WSS 3.0 Permissions Add docs but not change

Tags: wss-3.0

Is there a security configuration in WSS 3 that would allow end-users to add documents to a site, but then not be able to change this document?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to configure document lists to accept email messages with attachments? If so, then you could configure your list to accept messages from any address while granting read-only access.

This is easy to do with Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server, and that's built on top of WSS 3.